# Nested random effects group size using lme (in nlme)

Tags: r, random-variable, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I'm wrestling with a question regarding random effects that I haven't been able to figure out with my regular resources. I am examining the effects of two treatments (heat and water) on plant biomass data that I've collected for 4 years in 20 plots (each plot has 4 quadrants that are not independent but are measured separately).

My `lme` model (using `nlme` in `R`) has two nested categorical random effects: year is nested within plot and quad such that my R script is the following:

```
lme(biomass ~ heat*water + ... + elevation, data, random=~1|plot/quad/year)
```

There are no error messages given and the model appears to run smoothly. I only have 4 levels for year (80 for plot/quad) and have read that that a low number of levels will make it hard to get accurate estimates of variance. I tried adding year as a fixed effect and get completely different results (there is a lot of year-to-year variability in my dependent variable).

My questions:

1. Is the small size of the second-level random effect much of a problem? Is it only the number of levels of the main random effect that I should worry about?
2. If you think having only 4 levels is a problem, how can I test to see if it is messing up my model? Collecting data for several more years just to correct this issue is not possible.

Below are the summary output of the model:

```
> summary(model)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  2327.316 2359.081 -1154.658

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | plot
        (Intercept)
StdDev:    13.89338

 Formula: ~1 | quad %in% plot
        (Intercept)
StdDev:    11.32595

 Formula: ~1 | year %in% quad %in% plot
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    18.00256  7.39362

Fixed effects: forbs ~ h * w + elevation 
                Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept) 1290.2549 2576.2021 183  0.5008360  0.6171
hy           -10.6171   10.5874  15 -1.0028063  0.3319
wy           -13.6224   10.3395  15 -1.3175078  0.2074
elevation     -0.3382    0.7265  15 -0.4654946  0.6483
hy:wy         37.1865   15.0869  15  2.4648273  0.0263

Correlation: 
          (Intr) hy     wy     elevtn
hy        -0.222                     
wy        -0.189  0.503              
elevation -1.000  0.220  0.187       
hy:wy      0.275 -0.728 -0.713 -0.274

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.76090000 -0.23913835 -0.02857524  0.19955752  1.39996632 

Number of Observations: 257
Number of Groups: 
                       plot            quad %in% plot   year %in% quad %in% plot 
                       20                         74                        257
```

Thanks for your help, and please let me know if I can provide any additional info. I'd be happy to send you my data and script if it helps.